Is there a way to use dependency injection of getx for floor
I am using floor and getx for a flutter application, and I'm trying to inject the floor db instance via getx:
put:
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../database/database.dart';

Future<void> getInit() async{
    await Get.putAsync<DB>(()=>DBService().init());
}

class DBService extends GetxService{
    Future<DB> init() async{
        final db=await $FloorDB.databaseBuilder('db.db').build();
        print(db.runtimeType);
        return db;
    }
}

find:
final db=Get.find<DB>();
db.iconDAO.ins(IconModel(null,'/test',0,0,255,255));

however, since the type of floor db instance is the autogenerated private _$DB class which extends DB class, putting works but for finding I got an error: _TypeError (type '_$DB' is not a subtype of type 'DB' in type cast)
I tried to call Get.put and Get.find with dynamic type, but then i lose all editor autocompletion for DB type, and maybe compile check dont work on that too
Is there a workaround for this? thx
